# Can't get django-autocomplete-light to work outside model form

Tags: python, django, autocomplete

I'm using django-autocomplete-light to populate my User (Person) dropdowns.  It works fine in my ModelForms, but in a separate non-model Form I can't get anything to come up.  The  [docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-autocomplete-widgets-in-non-model-forms) seem fairly clear, but I can't get it working.  I've tried the first and third options (they say ModelChoiceField--shouldn't it be ChoiceField?  I tried both anyway) but no luck.  I can't find anything else on the subject.

**forms.py**

```
class ReplaceUserForm(forms.Form):

    #user and old_user should be the same; this was just for illustration 

    old_user    = forms.CharField(
        widget=autocomplete_light.TextWidget('PersonAutocomplete'))
    user = forms.ChoiceField(Person.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('PersonAutocomplete'))
```

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
autocomplete_light.register(Person,
    search_fields=['first_name', 'last_name', 'username'],
    split_words=True,
    autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder': 'Find a user',},
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to include `{% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}` at the top of my template.  Grumble.